# Bootstrap, How can i align the text to be in the mis of the page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The text is now horizontally aligned, but i want it vertically

It should also be an solution with bootstrap (if possible)
and responsive for mobile devices, large screens, .. (if possible)!

```
        <div class="navbar navbar-default   navbar-static-bottom">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <ul>
                        <h2>Product</h2>
                        <li> <a href="templates.php">Templates</a></li> 
                        <li> <a href="pricing.php">Pricing</a></li>
                    </ul>

                    <ul>
                        <h2>Company</h2>
                        <li><a href="aboutus.php">About Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contact.php">Contact us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="terms.php">Terms of Servise</a></li>
                        <li><a href="policy.php">Privacy policy</a></li>
                    </ul>

                    <ul>
                        <h2>Language</h2>
                        <li><a href="login.php">Englisch</a></li>
                        <li><a href="login.php">German</a></li>
                        <li><a href="login.php">Srpski</a></li>
                    </ul>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="login.php">facebook</a></li>
                        <li><a href="login.php">kaaa</a></li>
                        <li><a href="login.php">kaaa</a></li>
                    </ul>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

share edit delete  flag

Comment: Could you try explaining that again? Really unclear what you want to do.

Comment: I want the text vertically aligned.

Comment: For now it is horizontally aligned

Comment: It's a `.navbar`... and a `.row`. Those are horizontal. Try to figure it out yourself first and then ask for help on specific issues.

Comment: So what should i write insteadof navbar / row? I tought an row makes the element vertically

Comment: Please read the documentation: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend changing `<div class="container">` to `<div class="container-fluid">` so it's fills the width of the parent div. Everything inside the `<div class="row">` should be wrapped with a `<div class="col-xs-12">` to make it full width of the row, and then add `style="text-align:center"` to the `col-xs-12` div to center your text for everything inside the `col-xs-12`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe nav-pills is the component you are looking for: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav-pills